# What is "Capabilities" in configtx yaml file of Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to create my own fabric network by taking reference of "basic network" and "First Network" provided in "fabric-samples"

I have came across section called "Capabilities" in "configtx" yaml file.

Kindly help me to understand significance of this section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [new feature](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/capability_requirements.html) added in Hyperledger Fabric 1.1 to enable us to manage system upgrades across a decentralized deployment spanning multiple organizations.

It is likely that in a large network, there may be nodes running different versions of the software. As new features are introduced, we need a means of ensuring deterministic execution, and hence we use this feature to ensure consistency of execution within a channel.

Capability requirements are defined per channel in the channel configuration (found in the channel’s most recent configuration block). The channel configuration contains three locations, each of which defines a capability of a different type.

- Channel: these capabilities apply to both peer and orderers and are
  located in the root Channel group.
- Orderer: apply to orderers only and are located in the Orderer group.
- Application: apply to peers only and are located in the Application group.

Only binaries that support a given capability specified in a channel's configuration block will be able to participate in that channel.

Please see the [docs](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/capability_requirements.html) for additional insight.